# I need to deploy a sharepoint solution

Tags: 2010

I have updated a theme on Sharepoint 2010 site. The site is a sandboxed development site. The changes consist of updates to a master page, new css and some small images files as used on the home page. There are also some web parts implemented on the home page.

Now these changes need to be deployed as part of a Sharepoint Solution to a production environment.

I don't have direct and full access to the server which is hosted by a third party.

So my question is, is it possible to create a SP Solution to be deployed and how can I create it?

(I didn't know before I started developing it, that I would be required to create the SP Solution)

I have the following tools, Sharepoint Designer 2012, Visual Studio 2010 Express

Answer (score 0):

You can deploy your changes as a solution to your local SP which then makes it available to download as a WSP solution file.  You can then download this file and upload to the SP that's hosted by the 3rd party. Keep and eye on some of the site features you have activated in your solution as if the 3rd party does not also have these it will give you a headache.

This will only really work if you have developed the solution in Visual Studio and deployed the whole thing as a solution (WSP)

If you have built the Masterpage, CSS and images files via SPD2012 then the easiest way is just to copy those changes across to Production environment manually, if its only changes to code then it shouldn't take to long.

You should be able to connect to the production SP using SPD.

Hope this helps.

S

Comment: How do I go about creating the solution from the existing files, I don't have a local SP, the dev environment is externally hosted by the third party.

Comment: Hi Jon, sorry I slightly misread your post... essentially you are wanting to migrate this from dev to production. I have edited my reply above.